# Innerjoin with orderBy or using groupBy on other table

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, inner-join, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 and Doctrine, and I have one problem with DQL query, I have two tables with Type and Product relationships, one Type can have many Products and one Product can have one Type. How do I write a query that will return the records to me sorted records by type and product relative to price?

```
public function getAllMainOrderByQueue()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->innerJoin('b.children', 'children')
        ->addSelect('children')
        ->andWhere('b.parent IS NULL')
        ->andWhere('b.isDeleted = :value')->setParameter('value', false)
        ->andWhere('children.isDeleted = :v')->setParameter('v', false)
        ->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('children.price', 'ASC')
    ;
}
```

When I'm using this code above I have an error:

> Cannot select distinct identifiers from query with LIMIT and ORDER BY
>   on a column from a fetch joined to-many association. Use output
>   walkers.

How to use **innerjoin** with orderBy function, maybe I should use groupBy on Product table?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your data looks like and what the query should return?

Comment: I have two type and product tables with a one-to-many relationship, one table (type) can contain many products. I need a query that will return all types sorted by the name and all Products that are sorted by type in the price.